# Move text element along with arc RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am using the following code to draw (and animate) an arc path with RaphaelJS;

```
    self.paper = Raphael(domElement, width, height);

    self.paper.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
        var alpha = 360 / total * value,
            a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
            x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
            y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
            path;
        if (total == value) {
            path = [
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
            ];
        }
        else {
            path = [
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
            ];
        }
        return { path: path };
    };

    self.arc = self.paper.path().attr({
        'fill':             'none',
        'stroke':           self.color,
        'stroke-opacity':   1,
        'stroke-width':     self.barWidth,
        'arc':              [self.centerX, self.centerY, 0, 100, position]
    };

    self.arc.animate({
        'arc': [self.centerX, self.centerY, domein.kennis, 100, position]
    }, self.duration, 'backOut');
```

Now a text label needs to move along with the arc. I'm having problems figuring out how to move the a text element along the path of the arc. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The problem is to position the text element correctly;

[see this question/jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479232/transforming-a-text-elements-position-relative-to-path-in-raphael-js)

Comment: You could do it manually: http://phrogz.net/svg/animation_on_a_curve.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Raphaël's [`animateWith()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animateWith) to link the text element animation with the arc's animation.

Comment: animateWith: Acts similar to Element.animate, but ensure that given animation runs in sync with another given element. In what way does that solve the problem of positioning the text element?

Comment: @ec30 why won't use the fiddle demonstrated in the linked question?

Comment: That's my fiddle and my question :) the point is the text element must be repositioned so that it is in front of the arc

Comment: @ec30 it seems that's *exactly* what's going on.