# Transforming a text element's position relative to path in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am building a custom chart with [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com) which includes arcs and percentages. The text label of an arc needs to move with the arc. I have achieved this by using the onAnimation callback and getting the point of the outer arc and position the text label accordingly:

```js
var paper = Raphael("paper", 200, 200);
var centerX = paper.width / 2;
var centerY = paper.height / 2;

// This is a dummy percentage; in real app this corresponds to actual value
var percentage = 0;

paper.customAttributes.arc = function(centerX, centerY, startAngle, endAngle, innerR, outerR) {
  var radians = Math.PI / 180,
    largeArc = +(endAngle - startAngle > 180),
    outerX1 = centerX + outerR * Math.cos((startAngle - 90) * radians),
    outerY1 = centerY + outerR * Math.sin((startAngle - 90) * radians),
    outerX2 = centerX + outerR * Math.cos((endAngle - 90) * radians),
    outerY2 = centerY + outerR * Math.sin((endAngle - 90) * radians),
    innerX1 = centerX + innerR * Math.cos((endAngle - 90) * radians),
    innerY1 = centerY + innerR * Math.sin((endAngle - 90) * radians),
    innerX2 = centerX + innerR * Math.cos((startAngle - 90) * radians),
    innerY2 = centerY + innerR * Math.sin((startAngle - 90) * radians);

  var path = [
    ["M", outerX1, outerY1],
    //move to the start point
    ["A", outerR, outerR, 0, largeArc, 1, outerX2, outerY2],
    //draw the outer edge of the arc
    ["L", innerX1, innerY1],
    //draw a line inwards to the start of the inner edge of the arc
    ["A", innerR, innerR, 0, largeArc, 0, innerX2, innerY2],
    //draw the inner arc
    ["z"]
    //close the path
  ];
  
  return {
    path: path
  };
};

var arc = paper.path().attr({
  'fill': "#cccccc",
  'stroke': 'none',
  'arc': [centerX, centerY, 0, 0, 60, 80]
});
arc.toBack();

var percentagesStart = 0;
var percentagesEnd = 0;
var percentagesDelta = 0;

var label = paper.text(
  arc.attrs.path[1][6],
  arc.attrs.path[1][7],
  "0").toFront();

label.attr({
  'font-size': 16,
  'fill': "#000000",
  'font-family': 'sans-serif',
  'text-anchor': 'middle'
});

arc.onAnimation(function(anim) {
  console.log("test");
  label.attr({
    x: this.attrs.path[1][6],
    y: this.attrs.path[1][7],
    text: (percentage++)
  });
});

arc.animate({
  'arc': [centerX, centerY, 0, 220, 60, 80]
}, 1000, 'easeInOut');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>

<div id="paper"></div>
```

However, the text label must be positioned where the arc ends, with some nice margin. The text element position must be transformed relative to the arc.

I have tried to use

```
label.transform("t-10,10");
```

And tried some other x, y values but that does not work, because at some point the x value has to be negative, and at some point the x value has to be positive, depending on the arc's angle.

Is there a way to position this correctly?

Comment: So you want this positioned after the arc, not on top of it? Also, the value of the label seems wrong, shows 53 most of the time.

Comment: the value of the label is indeed wrong; it is just a dummy number. In the real code I have the value right. The thing is I need the text label positioned after the arc, like you would see in real charts. The text followings along with the arc. So in the fiddle the text label needs to be positioned a bit up and a bit left (when arc is in lower left of circle) a bit up and a bit right (when arc is in upper left of circle), e a bit down and a bit right (when arc is in upper right of circle) and a bit down and a bit left (when arc is in lower right of circle). How to do this with transform?

Comment: why not calculate a diagonal for the text label to be used inside the arc's `onAnimation`?

Comment: either way he needs to have some math involved, to fix this properly :D